# perform update on basis of select query column using python

Tags: python

How to make the query of the update, after selecting in a way that if column 
initially does not have value in a table then perform an update on that column else does not perform an update using python.
The update query is mentioned below.

```
    sql_update = """Update table_name1 set column1 = %s, column2 = %s,column3=%s,column4=%s where column5 = %s"""
input = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd' , 1)
cursor.execute(sql_update , input)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

With sql you can do an update only on columns that have empty values as:

```
update table_name set col_1 = 1, col_2 = 2 where col_3 is null
```